# How to assign a custom role to new user in WordPress from registration form

Tags: wordpress, themes

I want to assign a custom user role in WordPress based on registration form. For example I have "teacher" and "student" on the registration form. I have to put two check boxes so that if user selects "student" they will be automatically assigned role of student instead of the default one.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an action hook for when the user registers and add the role there.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

    $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' ); // Optional, you don't have to remove this role if you want to keep subscriber as well
    $user->add_role( 'student' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Austin ! But the argument you are using called 'myplugin_registration_save' can be replaced with the name of the plugin which handle registration or can be anything else and please where exactly can i put these code ? in functions.php? thanks

Comment: `myplugin_` is just a prefix and can be replaced with anything you want (your plugin or theme prefix). And this code can be placed in `functions.php` or any other include file. Don't place it in a template file though because that may load too late.

Comment: Thank you very much ! My registration form is used by another plugin where only 3 fields ie. Firstname, Lastname, email only used for registration and others on same form used for entering others client details . I think i may use it in the registration plugin

Comment: @AustinWinstanley Thanks for the code, but it seems is not working when I had WooCommerce installed, it will register user as customer only. Any suggestion?